# Input field change it's position while on focus

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a form with material design. While not focus it looks good but when the field is focused, it's position towards left.
You can check the image for more details, and you can also see the distance between two field.

[image]

[image]

Here is HTML:

```css
  form.login-form {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    margin: 40px auto;
  }
  label{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top:0px;
    left:-184px;
    color:#999;
    font-family:'Helvetica', sans-serif;
    font-size:16px;
    z-index:1;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  }
  input{
    display:inline-block;
    position: relative;
    background:none;
    border:none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
    font-family: 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-size: 16px;
    z-index:2;
  }
  input:focus , input:valid{
    outline:none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #830303;
    position: relative;
  }
  input:focus + label,input:valid + label{
    top:-17px;
    font-size:11px;
    color:#830303;
    background-position: 0 0; 
  }
```

```html
<form action="#" method="" class="login-form">
    <div class="loginformgrid">
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="username" required  autocomplete="off">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" required autocomplete="off" >
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <button class="login-button" type="submit" value="submit">Login</button>
      </div>
      <div class="belowloginformgrid">
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" name="remeberme"> Remember me
          <a href="#">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;   Forgot password?</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: `position: auto` is invalid... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue your having is due to the label resizing on focus. As you have the `transition:all` on label which applies it to all the properties and as your font size is getting smaller so the label takes in less space and hence the default inline spacing of your controls shrinks. Set the width of your label to a default size to fix it so that it does not change with the transition and remains the same for it to not shrink the space in between.

```
label{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top:0px;
  left:-184px;
  color:#999;
  font-family:'Helvetica', sans-serif;
  font-size:16px;
  z-index:1;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
  width:100px; /* Add this to keep it same when transitioning*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

edit your `css` code:

```
label {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
```

and add id : `id="password"` to `label`.

and add this `css` code:

```
#password{
  left: 182px !important;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p46gsfLe/)

Answer (score 0):

I've rearranged the label and input, and added an additional span tag.

```css
form.login-form {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 40px auto;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;

}
label span {
  color: #999;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  font-family: 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top: -1.5em;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in;}

input {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #aaa;
  font-family: 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 16px;
  z-index: 2;
}

input:focus,
input:valid {
  outline: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #830303;
}

input:focus+span,
input:valid+span {
  margin-top: -3.5em;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #830303;
  background-position: 0 0;
}
```

```html
<form action="#" method="" class="login-form">
  <div class="loginformgrid">
    <div>
      <label for="username">
        <input type="text" name="username" required autocomplete="off">
        <span>Username</span>
      </label>
      <label for="password">
        <input type="password" name="password" required autocomplete="off">
        <span>Password</span>
      </label>
      
      <button class="login-button" type="submit" value="submit">Login</button>
    </div>
    <div class="belowloginformgrid">
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="remeberme"> Remember me
        <a href="#">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;   Forgot password?</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: If you edit your question after a comment, please do it on the original question and not inside of an answer. More, please let us know if that fixed the problem or the problem is still there. Thanks.